Disable a `contextMenu` button conditionally depending on the list item
I'm using SwiftData with SwiftUI. I want to disable a contextMenu button on a list item conditionally depending on the list item itself.
E.g.
I have a parent-child model as one-to-many relationship. On ParentListView, I need to disable the contextMenu button if parent.children is not empty.
Once user deletes the children in another ChildrenListView, switching back to the ParentView should now enable the delete button.
struct ParentListView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  private var parents: [Parent]

  // Intention: only allow delete if parent.children is empty
  // And parent.children can be updated in another ChildrenView
  @State private var disableDelete = true

  var body: some View {
    List(parents) { parent in
      MyListItemView(parent)
        .contextMenu {
          Button {
            if parent.children.isEmpty {
              modelContext.delete(parent)
            }
          } label: {
            Text("Delete")
          }
          .disabled(disableDelete)
          // TODO: this doesn't work. Question: (a) why? (b) how to fix?
          .onAppear {
            if parent.children.isEmpty {
              disableDelete = false
            } else {
              disableDelete = true
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}

Question:

The onAppear seems to be triggered upon rendering the whole ParentListView, not the contextMenu button. Why? (and what's the general rule when this can happen?)
how to fix it? I think I'm flexible in terms of UI presentation. E.g. it doesn't have to be a contextMenu, it can be a button next to the list item, a command menu or something else suit for the job.

For context, I'm trying to find a workaround for SwiftData crash on deletion
with relation by manually implementing the deleteRule: .deny.
Update 1:
I think it's a bug in SwiftData. A workaround as of 4/9/24 is to make the child model's var parent: Parent? optional instead of required and use deleteRule: .cascade or nullify. Have to enforce restrictions manually in code.
Appendix: MRE
ExampleModel.swift
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Parent {
  @Attribute(.unique) var name: String
  @Relationship(deleteRule: .deny, inverse: \Child.parent)
  var children: [Child] = []
  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

@Model
final class Child {
  @Attribute(.unique) var name: String
  var parent: Parent

  init(name: String, parent: Parent) {
    self.name = name
    self.parent = parent
  }
}

ExampleView.swift
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  @Query private var parents: [Parent]
  @Query private var children: [Child]
  @State private var disableDelete = true

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List(parents) { parent in
        Text(parent.name)
          .contextMenu {
            Button {
              modelContext.delete(parent)
            } label: {
              Text("Delete")
            }
            // TODO: this doesn't work. Question: (a) why? (b) how to fix?
            .disabled(disableDelete)
            .onAppear {
              if !parent.children.isEmpty {
                disableDelete = true
              } else {
                disableDelete = false
              }
            }
          }
      }

      Spacer()

      Button {
        addNewParent()
      } label: {
        Text("Add parent")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .bold()
      }
      .background()


      Divider()

      List(children) { child in
        Text("\(child.name) from: \(child.parent.name)")
          .contextMenu {
            Button {
              modelContext.delete(child)
            } label: {
              Text("Delete")
            }
          }
      }

      Spacer()

      Button {
        addNewChild()
      } label: {
        Text("Add child")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .bold()
      }
      .background()
    }
  }

  func addNewParent() {
    let newParent = Parent(
      name: "New Parent " + Int.random(in: 1...100).description
    )
    modelContext.insert(newParent)
  }

  func addNewChild() {
    let newChild = Child(
      name: "New Child " + Int.random(in: 1...100).description
      ,
      parent: parents.randomElement()!
    )
    modelContext.insert(newChild)
  }
}

#Preview {
  ExampleView()
    .modelContainer(
      for: [
        Parent.self,
        Child.self
      ], inMemory: true
    )
}

How to reproduce:

AddParent
Right click parent, expect delete button enabled
AddChild
Right click parent, expect delete button disabled



How about .disabled(!parent.children.isEmpty)? I don't see why you need an extra @State here.

@Sweeper I added clarification to question. "Once user deletes the children in another ChildrenListView, switching back to the ParentView should now enable the delete button. " The issue I'm having is that SwiftData doesn't refresh Parent.childrenList when add/delete the children. (tried call modelContext.save() but it still doesn't refresh) feels there's a missing link

Yes more information is needed here but perhaps you could test to make parents into a Query and see if it works then to check parent.children.isEmpty directly. This might not fit into your view structure but is interesting as a test to see if the issue is that changes to your parents array doesn't trigger a UI update

updated with a MRE appendix. @Sweeper
